# rails で 画像アップロードの前に既存画像と入れ替えてプレビューしたい

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

画像プレビュー時に、既存画像の横に、新規プレビュー画像が出ます。
既存画像と入れ替えるように、表示させるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

```
<div class="field">
  <%= image_tag @user.picture.url if @user.picture? %>
  <%= f.label :picture, '画像' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :picture_cache %>
  <img id="img_prev" width=200 height=200 src="#" class="img-thumbnail  hidden"/>
  <%= f.file_field :picture, :id => 'post_post_img' %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img_prev').attr('src', e.target.result);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }
      $("#post_post_img").change(function() {
        $('#img_prev').removeClass('hidden');
        readURL(this);
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

既存画像を表示するimage_tagにidを付与して、ファイルの選択時にそのDOMのsrcを変更するという方法ではどうですか？（以下は例です）

```
<div class="field">
  <%= image_tag @user.picture.url, id: "img_prev" if @user.picture? %>
  <%= f.label :picture, '画像' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :picture_cache %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture, :id => 'post_post_img' %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img_prev').attr('src', e.target.result);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }
      $("#post_post_img").change(function() {
        readURL(this);
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```